# Cannot upload to BlackBerry World because System.exit calls not allowed

Tags: blackberry-10, blackberry-playbook, blackberry-android

I have some problems when i try to upload my ported BAR file from Android source code:

```
?   There were 1 imported across 1 new bundle.
?   Please review your imported release for errors.
?   error in opening zip file System.exit calls not allowed!
?   Invalid binary file (._xxxx_xxxx9144169860289695202._xxxx_xxxx)
?   Invalid binary file (.classpath8029703777285450457.classpath)
?   Invalid binary file (.project6368383898458048449.project)
?   Invalid binary file (AndroidManifest.xml6041251884878318023.xml)
?   Invalid binary file (lint.xml4949050568352344802.xml)
?   Invalid binary file (project.properties2478192746766803707.properties)
?   Invalid binary file (._.classpath1279851333217904503.classpath)
?   Invalid binary file (._.project4963501103302439211.project)
?   Invalid binary file (._.settings6403994606986425206.settings)
?   Invalid binary file (._AndroidManifest.xml7465961263356524197.xml)
?   Invalid binary file (._assets7820763530849924867._assets)
?   Invalid binary file (._bin4158243671404695308._bin)
?   Invalid binary file (._gen1637939995840746927._gen)
?   Invalid binary file (._lint.xml1798100153005616928.xml)
?   Invalid binary file (._project.properties5961637973232398652.properties)
?   Invalid binary file (._res6434086574236390329._res)
?   Invalid binary file (._src2834477385955816881._src)
?   Invalid binary file (org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs4155356269041672159.prefs)
?   Invalid binary file (._org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs9193271982940470960.prefs)
?   Invalid binary file (xxx.png3405033461431571502.png)
?   Invalid binary file (xxx.png4185722626726835686.png)
?   Invalid binary file (xxx.png6629508964401705944.png)
?   Invalid binary file (xxx.png3951634087592980248.png)
?   Invalid binary file (xxx.png6610366709435995090.png)
?   Invalid binary file (xxx.png1462654443485611662.png)
?   Invalid binary file (xxx.png8028919413158108187.png)
?   Invalid binary file (xxx.png4161610266299604612.png)
?   Invalid binary file (xxx.png5044369819175750647.png)
?   Invalid binary file (xxx.png5478583367906230563.png)
?   Invalid binary file (xxx.png5690369531509857973.png)
?   Invalid binary file (xxx.png6665571246252631333.png)
?   Invalid binary file (xxx.png3067066318731066885.png)
?   Invalid binary file (xxx.png6182415731813752828.png)
?   Invalid binary file (xxx.png5564879140277324991.png)
?   Invalid binary file (xxx.png4168273330724460934.png)
?   Invalid binary file (xxx.png7424605744156994400.png)
?   Invalid binary file (xxx.png2143495245658084337.png)
?   Invalid binary file (xxx.png3892067674043532572.png)
?   Invalid binary file (xxx.png4328939009206690917.png)
?   Invalid binary file (xxx.png7250101288947739322.png)
?   Invalid binary file (xxx.png7628414616850024800.png)
?   Invalid binary file (xxx.png2957123836880933253.png)
?   Invalid binary file (xxx.png4353124853960754842.png)
?   Invalid binary file (xxxx_03a.png7757004586244259927.png)
?   Invalid binary file (xxxx_04.png5609950302680314331.png)
?   Invalid binary file (xxxx_05a.png7024629859302122584.png)
?   Invalid binary file (xxxx_06a.png945221159178482861.png)
?   Invalid binary file (xxxx_07a.png7840661270791463333.png)
?   Invalid binary file (xxxx_10a.png6537401483977947062.png)
?   Invalid binary file (xxxx_11a.png4089299093947598209.png)
?   Invalid binary file (xxxx_12a.png3914559505571699107.png)
?   Invalid binary file (xxxx_13a.png4237917822965060007.png)
?   Invalid binary file (xxxx_14a.png4420968238125384725.png)
?   Invalid binary file (xxxx_16a.png4065488083709433818.png)
?   Invalid binary file (xxxx_17a.png5873048186416020071.png)
?   Invalid binary file (xxxx_18a.png8827417423356601674.png)
?   Invalid binary file (xxxx_19a.png8070767671513894861.png)
?   Invalid binary file (xxxx_20a.png6509217252450288713.png)
?   Invalid binary file (xxx.png1676755072511485567.png)
?   Invalid binary file (xxx.png282227566932005746.png)
?   Invalid binary file (xxx.png7708237495757376660.png)
?   Invalid binary file (xxx.png1138657404332473780.png)
?   Invalid binary file (xxx.png8537802648820188227.png)
```

But my bar run normally in my Playbook simulator.

How can i fix this?

Thanks you

Comment: Looks like the problem is only when signing. Make sure your bar file is ok and follow [this guide](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Testing-and-Deployment/How-to-sign-your-BAR-file-from-the-command-line/ta-p/944647)

Comment: i follow this guide : http://crackberry.com/how-sign-convert-and-install-android-files-your-blackberry-playbook-using-windows-or-mac in mac osx